# 'NewPageIndex' is not a member of 'System.Event.Args'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-controls, page-index-changed

Afternoon All,

I have a simple gridview with list items items that have been uploaded to file.  I had an issue with paging on my gridview.  As i selected page two the webpage would fail.

After looking aroud on the internet, i have seem that i need to add a PageIndexChanging' event to my gridview.  I have tried to complete this via the following code but have a issue with `e.NewPageIndex`, this has an error that states... 'NewPageIndex' is not a member of 'System.Event.Args'.

Here is the vb for the PageIndexChanging event...

```
Protected Sub UploadedFiles_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UploadedFiles_PageIndexChanging
    UploadedFiles.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    UploadedFiles.DataBind()
End Sub
```

And here is my gridview code...

```
       <asp:GridView  ID="UploadedFiles" 
           DataSource="<%# GetUploadList() %>" 
           runat="server" 
           CssClass="mGrid" 
           Width="300px"   
           PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" 
           AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"  
           CellPadding="4" 
           ForeColor="#333333" 
           AllowPaging="True" 
           PageSize="2" 
           AllowSorting="True" > 
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
        <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
       </asp:GridView>
```

Many thanks in advance for an help.

Regards
Betty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong signature - try this:

```
Protected Sub UploadedFiles_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles UploadedFiles_PageIndexChanging
```

Comment: I have added the'GridViewPageEvents' part to my code.   However i now have an error stating 'Identifier Expected' at the end on the first line of code.  I was that the ' Handles UploadedFiles_PageIndexChanging.' didnt require anything but this insists on a (.) and then more additional code?

Comment: Usually that means you have a misplaced colon or bracket.  I added 'Protected Sub' to the signature in case there is misunderstanding on how it should start.

Comment: just what i thought.  I have solved this by removing the line of code and then adding this back in again with intelisence.  Many thanks for your help.  This works a treat now.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`PageIndexChanging` event on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanging.aspx), notice that it doesn't take an `EventArgs`, it takes a [`GridViewPageEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewpageeventargs.aspx). `GridViewPageEventArgs` does have a [`NewPageIndex` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewpageeventargs.aspx).